# Extract text from HTML without losing the structure

Tags: python, html, selenium

Is there any easy way of extracting the text from the HTML source without losing structure (specifically line breaks and spaces).

Currently, I am extracting text as follows:

```
page_title_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("x-path")
page_title = page_title_element.text
```

However, this method distorts the structure of the text.

I am using Python and Selenium.

**Edit:**

I am essentially trying to extract the data from the whole page (complete text data of HTML pages) and not from individual tags.

Comment: Can you share HTML sample with the text?

Comment: I have updated the answer please check once.

Comment: @JaSON I may not be able to provide the website or its data. Is it possible that I make this clear to you in some other way?

Comment: Share piece of HTML code for target node. Replace sensitive data if it contains any - just preserve the node structure

Comment: What is the point of extracting text from the whole page? It will be messy. If you want to get text as pretty as it appears on page then you won't get it anyway cause the point of HTML, CSS, JS is to make data look pretty-structured to user

Comment: @JaSON I need all the text and I want it to be pretty as its corresponding HTML. Is there an alternative way/idea to approach this problem? You can just give an idea and I will develop on that.

Comment: You can try to make screenshot of page or download HTML along with all other files like JS, CSS, images...

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to access the source of element. This means getting the innerHTML information as they do with JavaScript which doesn't exist in the case of a python code.

Here's how to do it

```
page_title_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("x-path")
page_title = page_title_element.source
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is not text. Also the `source` object does not exist for `WebElement`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use below code for that.

```
data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html").get_attribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is not text.

Comment: It is working for java. I have updated for python. Please use updated answer.